# Unable to use scrollview in .kv files

Tags: python, kivy

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before but for some reason scrollview isn't working for me in kivy. I'm quite new to this so please don't be too harsh. I keep running into this issue:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm trying to have a scrollbar to use in another longer program, but I need to first figure out how scroll view works in kivy. I'd be very appreciative if someone could tell me what is wrong with this code.

This is my .kv file

```
    <MenuScreen>:
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Write'
                on_press: app.write()
                size_hint: .3, .2
                background_color: 1, 2, 1, 1
                pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .4}
    <WritingScreen>:
            ScrollView:
                do_scroll_x: False
                do_scroll_y: True
                Label:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    text_size: self.width
                    padding: 10, 10
                    text:
                        'really some amazing text\n' * 100
```

This is my .py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file('text.kv')


# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class WritingScreen(Screen):
    pass


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(WritingScreen(name='Write'))
screens = [Screen(name='Title {}'.format(i)) for i in range(2)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

    # show the scrollview
    def write(self):
        sm.current = 'Write'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Kivy and Python are very particular about indentation. In your `text.kv` the indentation of the `ScrollView` line is wrong. Another issue is the line:

```
text_size: self.width
```

The `text_size` attribute is expecting two values, so providing just one value will cause an error. I don't think you need that line anyway.

Here is a modified version of your `text.kv' file that will work:

```
<MenuScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Write'
            on_press: app.write()
            size_hint: .3, .2
            background_color: 1, 2, 1, 1
            pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .4}
<WritingScreen>:
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            # text_size: self.width
            padding: 10, 10
            text:
                'really some amazing text\n' * 100
```